# Install Ruby Bash

Tags: ruby, linux, bash

I needed universal bash script which checks installing Ruby and if one doesn't exist then installs it on Linux and after that runs ruby scipt

What I have now:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo apt-get install ruby

ruby "`dirname $0`/bin/manager.rb"
```

> Solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR=$(which ruby)

DIR=$(dirname $DIR)

if [ ! -d $DIR 2>/dev/null ]; then
  echo "Ruby doesn't exist. We install them"
  echo "Input SUDO password for install:"
  sudo apt-get install ruby   
fi

ruby "`dirname $0`/bin/manager.rb"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR=$(which ruby)

DIR=$(dirname $DIR)

if [ ! -d $DIR 2>/dev/null ]; then
  echo "Ruby doesn't exist. We install them"
  echo "Input SUDO password for install:"
  sudo apt-get install ruby   
fi

ruby "`dirname $0`/bin/manager.rb"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -f /.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby ]; then
    sudo apt-get install ruby
    ruby dirname $0`'/bin/manager.rb'
else
    ruby dirname $0`'/bin/manager.rb'
fi
```

Just do `which ruby`, that'll give you your ruby location. Replace `/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby` with that location. And run the script.

Comment: Type `which ruby` in the terminal . It is the path that'll be there in your `$PATH`

Comment: This is bash script .

Comment: But for each computer, command "which ruby" return different path. I want universal script

Comment: just store ouput of which ruby in a variable and then pass that variable to the if statement.

Comment: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-bsd-appleosx-bash-assign-variable-command-output/

Comment: It's works thanks. But if ruby doesn't install "if [ ! -d $DIR ];" will work right?

Comment: It should. try it out. if it doesn't leave the error here .